# In C and C++, how does the linker find the right file with the implemented functions?

Tags: c++, c, linker

This is code I have in C. I am used to Java, and as such I don't understand how the C compiler finds the right source file with the implemented methods.

For example, if I put sample_c1.cpp file with Main.cpp it will go to the on_start() of sample_c1.cpp. If I delete sample_c1.cpp and put the sample_c2.cpp with Main.c it will go to the on_start() of sample_c2.cpp.

Here is my test program:

#### Main.c

```
//no includes to sample_c1.cpp or sample_c2.cpp

void on_start();
void on_stop();
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    on_start();
    return 0;
}
```

#### sample_c1.cpp

```
//this is all i have in the file no class definition no nothing just implementations of the methods 
void on_start(){
    ....
}

void on_stop(){
    ......
}
```

#### sample_c2.cpp

```
//this is all i have in the file no class definition no nothing just implementations of the methods 
void on_start(){
    ....
}

void on_stop(){
    ......
}
```

Comment: There are no "classes" in C.

Comment: C doesn't have classes, and `cpp` indicates it's C++. It's extremely important when programming to know which language in which  you're programming.

Comment: @KenWhite It may be C++, but this code is also valid C, and the answer is the same for both.

Comment: @user63898 How are you compiling and linking your program?

Comment: using VC++ Compile as C++ Code (/TP)

Comment: Please be aware that C and C++ are two different languages. You may want to figure out which one you want before trying to program.

Comment: no problem , its not my code i trying to figure how does this code i have work

Comment: @immibis: The question asks about *how the linker finds the right CLASS* for C code, so the question itself makes no sense. As I said, C doesn't have classes. The poster needs to first learn which language they are using, and then edit the question to fix it so that it isn't nonsense. A question about *C classes* has no future value here, because *C classes* don't exist. Whether the code is C or C++ is irrelevant - what matters is what has value to future users of this site.

Comment: @KenWhite The asker seems to be confusing source files with classes, coming from a Java background where they're roughly equivalent. I've edited the question to fix that. Chill out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE tells the compiler* the names of all the source files in your project. The compiler* processes them all at once. If it sees you're calling a function that isn't defined in the same source file, then it will look in the other source files. If you have a file called `sample_c1.cpp` then it will look there. If you have a file called `sample_c2.cpp` then it will look there. If you have a file called `travel_back_in_time_and_murder_hitler.cpp` then it will look there.

There's nothing exciting happening, really. There is no "classpath" like in Java. Just a bunch of source files that make a program.

* Actually the linker, but the difference between compilers and linkers is out-of-scope of this question. It's basically just another part of the compiler.

Comment: well its first time i see this , i done C++ but always i had to include the headers

Comment: @user63898 The headers contain the prototypes. Headers are an alternative to manually retyping (or copy-pasting) all the prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, compiling a program with multiple definitions of a symbol that has external linkage causes undefined behavior.

In practice, the linker will usually throw an error when you do this.

Comment: @BillLynch As I understand it, the asker only uses one of those files at a time.